# Probability for not finding a product

Tags: probability, random-variables

> A product is exist in $\frac{1}{4}$ of chain stores. One decided looking for the product in not more than 5 stores. Defining $X$ to be number of searched stores, find:
>
> a.Distribution of $X$
>
> b.Expected value and variance
>
> c. given he looked in two stores and didn't find the product, what's the probability he won't find it at all?

About A: If he looked in $k=1,...,5$ stores, he didn't find the product in k-1 stores and found it in the last store so the probability is $\frac{1}{4}(\frac 3 4)^{k-1}$, so the distribution is [image]

but since the sum of probabilities is 1, it follows that $P(X=0)=0.501$. Why this result is intuitively correct.

About B:I found just by looking at the table that $E[X]=0.8271,Var(X)=0.9984$.

About C:if we define $B\text{-number of stores he  looked and didn't find it}$ we are lookign for $P(B=5\mid X=2)=\frac{P(B=5,X=2)}{P(X=2)}=\frac{P(B=5)}{P(X=2)}=\frac{(\frac 3 4) ^5}{\frac 3 {16}}=1.2656$ which is obviously wrong.

How can I explain/find $P(X=0)$ and why C is not correct?

Comment: If you look in two stores and you want to find the P that the product isn't there, isn't it 3/4 times 3/4? Or are you intending to look in a second store, if the product is sighted in the first store? In that case, P(X=1) should be 3/4

Comment: Why $P(X=1)=0.75$? If I searched only one store I necessarily found the productand stopped searching , isn't it?

Comment: in that case P(X=3) is incorrect, numerator should be 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we go into a store, let $S$ stand for success, the store had it, and let $F$ stand for failure. Note that the probability of success is $\frac{1}{4}$ and the probabiliy of failure is $\frac{3}{4}$

As you had it, $\Pr(X=1)=\Pr(S)=\frac{1}{4}$.

$\Pr(X=2)=\Pr(FS)=\frac{3}{4}\cdot \frac{1}{4}=\frac{3}{16}$.

$\Pr(X=3)=\Pr(FFS)=\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{4}=\frac{9}{64}$.

$\Pr(X=4)=\Pr(FFFS)=\frac{27}{256}$.

For $\Pr(X=5)$ things are a little different, because of the "give up" condition. There are two ways to find $\Pr(X=5)$. We could add up the probabilities previously obtained, and subtract the sum from $1$. Or else we can note that $X=5$ if we have four failures in a row. So $\Pr(X=5)=\frac{81}{256}$.

Mean and variance are somewhat tedious calculations. I will assume that, now that you have the distribution, you can carry them out.

We turn to the conditional probability problem. First we do it mechanically.

Let $A$ be the event "looked without success in two stores" and $B$ the event "won't find." We want $\Pr)B|A)$, which by definition is
$$\frac{\Pr(A\cap B)}{\Pr(A)}.$$
The top is just the probability of $FFFFF$. This is $(3/4)^5$. The bpttom is the probability of $FF$. This is $(3/4)^2$. Divide. We get $(3/4)^3$.

**Remark:** The answer to the conditional probability problem is clear without all the symbols. **Given** that we failed twice, the probability we will strike out completely is $(3/4)^3$, since we now are going only to three stores.

Comment: Why in A X cant get 0 (if he looked in 0 zeroes)?

Comment: It is an interpretation of the meaning of the question. The person goes to stores until she/he has either (i) found the object or (ii) has gone to $5$ stores. So the number of stores visited can never be $0$, since if we go to $0$ stores we won't find the object.

Comment: It's that interpretation that made me doubt exactly how to set it up, hence my first comment to the poster. Your approach makes sense though

Comment: There is some potential ambiguity that caused you trouble. But in this case I have no doubt that the go stores suntil you succeed or until you get tired is the intended interpretation. Thus $0$ stores is not an option. Neither is going to two stores, failing, and going home.

Comment: hypergeometric distribution?

Comment: @imranfat: The closest fit is a geometric distribution, apart from the no more than $5$ clause.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant, geometric distribution.

Comment: With many of the standard distributions, there are **truncated** relatives, where we cut off at a certain point.  For example, with lighbulbs we might have a policy of replacing when they die, or even if they don't die, at say $1200$ hours. The use-life of a lightbulb will have a truncated distribution much like here the store visits did.